# What is the maximum memory allocated to a process (any .net application)

Tags: .net, windows, memory-management, process

I was trying to learn the various aspects of memory allocation to a any (.net) process on OS, especially on Windows OS.

1. So if we presume that all .net executable are dependent upon Stack and Heap for it's memory. Then question would be what is the maximum size of Stack and Heap?
2. Continuing on this assumption, Garbage Collection would only (try to) clean the Heap memory. [Stack is not controlled by GC. - Correct?]

- So there are different memory limits sets for each generations
- Gen 0 = 256 K
- Gen 1 = 2 MB
- Gen 2 = 10 MB

2.1 Let's consider we have only one process is running. Does this mean a process can consume maximum 12.25MB only?

2.2 Does this memory allocation would differ with respect to other OS like MAC, Linux.

3. Also, a .net process/app would run under AppDomain so how much memory is allocated to a AppDomain?
4. Multiple AppDomains would be running under IIS (w3wp.exe). So how much memory would be allocated to w3wp.exe process.
5. Curious to know if IIS is one of the process running on OS, and there are others too (# of different system and non-system programs are running). Then what is the maximum memory allocation to such processes. Is there any policy applied by OS to categories processes and allocate memory accordingly.
6. With respect to #5, is the RAM size is the maximum memory utilized by all processes on any OS?

Apologizes for multiple questions however they sounds like related to one topic.

*Note: Answers/comments for each point separately would be appreciable, rather than generic comments.

Comment: What is the relevance of the `c++` tag to this .NET question?

Comment: @Eljay: Accidental addition, removed it.

Comment: The actual answer is `the same as any other Windows process`. All available from 64-bit processes, 2GB

Comment: If a .NET app could only consume 12.5MB of memory, we wouldn't even talk about .NET in 2020. It will of course be able to consume all available memory corresponding to the process' architecture

Comment: Why the question?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Can you elaborate. If RAM is 4GB and HDD is 100GB. Exactly how much memory?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thx. So if we have 4GB RAM (assuming you are saying RAM is the memory that is used for it), theoretically max 2 processes can run consuming maximum limit. (I understand practically no prog reaches that limit.) 
Why? - Just curious to know about it.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/managed-code - when you talk about memory it's never HDD

Comment: @San I suspect there's a misunderstanding about what RAM is or how all computers work with memory.